# Show signals in ModelSim

Tags: fpga, modelsim

I wrote a synchronous BCD counter. The counter count from 0 to 9, and so on and I want to see the signals (inputs & outputs) in ModelSim to verify the code I wrote.
So how can i see the signals?
Do I need to add something to my code or I need to run some function in ModelSim?

thanks,
Aviv

Comment: This venue perhaps shouldn't be viewed as the first resort for help before attempting to find answers to basic questions using Modelsim documentation. See [Modelsim getting started](https://supportnet.mentor.com/files/public/about/startprod/modelsim_getting_started.pdf) for instance, starting where it says "Run the Simulation" on Page 7. Googling can find third party help specific for VHDL such as [Simulating VHDL code using Modelsim VHDL Software](http://appliedelectronicsengineering.blogspot.com/2015/03/simulating-vhdl-code-using-modelsim.html).

Comment: There are webinars you can register to view, such as [ModelSim Essentials](http://www.mentor.com/products/fv/multimedia/modelsim-essentials) and [ModelSim GUI Essentials](http://www.mentor.com/products/fv/multimedia/modelsim-gui-essentials-webinar). You can google for *modelsim tutorial vhdl* and filter for videos,...

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have stored the source code of BCD counter and it's testbench in same file. (Let it be **BCDcounter.v**)

> Then you just right click on **BCDcounter.v** and click `compile`.
>
> Then if compilation was successful you will right click again the file(the name of the testbench file suppose it is **BCDtestbench**) and click `simulate`.
>
> Then a new window will appear. Now in the left pane you will see the same filename that you simulated. Right click on that and select `Add to` ->`Add to wave`-> `All items in design`. Then `run` it.

Note: you may want to set the `run-length` appropiately.

Comment: @aviv yakoobi.: Don't just ask questions. Try yourself and also look at the answer given.

Comment: @aviv yakoobi.: Atleast upvote or accept it if it was useful. that is what makes the post useful for future users.